# The necessity of quote in On Lisp's #[ read macro?

Tags: common-lisp, reader-macro, on-lisp

I am reading On Lisp and cannot make out why the code below has use a quote.  Here is the excerpt from the text:

> Another character combination reserved for the user is #[. Figure 17.3
>   gives an example of how this character might be defined as a more
>   elaborate kind of left parenthesis. It defines an expression of the
>   form #[x y] to read as a list of all the integers between x and y,
>   inclusive:
>
> ```
> #[2 7]
> (2 3 4 5 6 7)
> ```
>
> #### Figure 17.3: A read-macro defining delimiters.
>
> ```
> (set-macro-character #\] (get-macro-character #\)))
>
> (set-dispatch-macro-character #\# #\[
>                               #'(lambda (stream char1 char2)
>                                    (let ((accum nil)
>                                          (pair (read-delimited-list #\] stream t)))
>                                      (do ((i (ceiling (car pair)) (1+ i)))
>                                          ((> i (floor (cadr pair)))
>                                           (list 'quote (nreverse accum)))
>                                        (push i accum)))))
>
>          Figure 17.3: A read-macro defining delimiters.
> ```

I do not understand why the line in the result form for the **do**is **(list 'quote (nreverse accum)))** rather than  **(nreverse accum)**.  Because we can run the code which does not using quote below without problem, right?

```
(let ((acc nil))
  (do ((i 2 (1+ i)))
      ((> i 7)
       (nreverse acc))
    (push i acc)))
```

Does any one know the trick here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter the new syntax at a Lisp listener, the reader would return a list of numbers. Evaluating this list of numbers would be an error, since Lisp expects a function or macro as the head of a list. Lists are not evaluating to themselves, as vectors, numbers, hash tables, ... are.

Thus you have two choices:

1. have the user write a quote in front of the interval expression to prevent evaluation
2. return a quoted list

Here we see choice 2.

```
CL-USER 7 > (read-from-string "#[5 10]")
(QUOTE (5 6 7 8 9 10))

CL-USER 8 > (eval (read-from-string "#[5 10]"))
(5 6 7 8 9 10)

CL-USER 9 > (let ((e #[5 10]))
              (describe e))

(5 6 7 8 9 10) is a LIST
0      5
1      6
2      7
3      8
4      9
5      10
```

If the reader macro would not return a quote list form, we would have to write:

```
CL-USER 10 > (let ((e '#[5 10]))   ; notice the QUOTE
               (describe e))

(5 6 7 8 9 10) is a LIST
0      5
1      6
2      7
3      8
4      9
5      10
```

Hmm, I would personally actually prefer the latter, having to write the quote explicitly.

I get:

```
CL-USER 17 > '(#[5 10] #[20 25])
((QUOTE (5 6 7 8 9 10)) (QUOTE (20 21 22 23 24 25)))
```

But I would have preferred:

```
CL-USER 18 > '(#[5 10] #[20 25])
((5 6 7 8 9 10) (20 21 22 23 24 25))
```

Comment: Hi Rainer, I still do not understand why the list in the set-dispatch-macro-character block is evaluated but not the list in the let block of my last piece of code (a sample).

Comment: @user1461328: I recommend that you try Rainer's read-from-string examples with your let form. (read-from-string "(let ..."), and, separately, pass that result to eval. The lists are being evaluated in exactly the same cases, but in the #[...] case the list starts with quote and in the (let ...) case it starts with let.